# coalesced read short integer cuda

Tags: cuda

say I want to load an array of short from global memory to shared memory. I am not sure how coalescing works here. On best practice guide, it says on device of compute capability 1.0 or 1.1, the k-th thread in a half warp must access the k-th word in a segment aligned to 16 times the size of the elements being accessed.

If I understand it correctly, in case I break my data into 32bytes (16 shorts) segments, thread id 0, 16, 32 ... has to access first element of each segment? do i need to consider 64bytes alignment or 128 bytes alignment as well? I have a gts 250, so i guess this is important. Advices are welcomed. thanks.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

According to Section G.3.2.1 of the [CUDA Programming Guide](http://developer.download.nvidia.com/compute/cuda/3_2/toolkit/docs/CUDA_C_Programming_Guide.pdf) `short` will not coalesce on Compute Capability 1.0 and 1.1 devices under **any** circumstances.  Specifically, it states:

> The size of the words accessed by the
>   threads must be 4, 8, or 16 bytes

You can however use vector types such as `short2`, `short4`, or even `short8` to get coalesced access.  The coalescing rules for these types is spelled out in Section G.3.2.1 as well.  However, as far as coalescing is concerned a `short2` is just like a 32-bit `int`.

FWIW, devices with Compute Capability 1.3 or greater handle types like `char` and `short` much better.  Reading `char`s on a 1.3 device might give you as much as ~60% of peak memory bandwidth vs. ~10% of peak memory bandwidth on a 1.0 or 1.1 device.